# Can I use "OR" in a CSS media query?

Tags: css, media

I'm trying to combine the following three media queries into one:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
}
```

I've tried this below, but it doesn't work:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
}
```

Is there a way to combine these, possibly with an "OR"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

> Here is an example of several media queries in a comma-separated list using the an @media-rule in CSS:
>   `@media screen and (color), projection and (color) { … }`

Only use `@media` at the start of the rule.